# Which elements have the min subelements XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the xml file:

```html
<sinonime>
 <cuvant titlu="timp">
  <definitie>durata care corespunde desfasurarii unui evenimen</definitie>
  <sens>vreme</sens>
  <sens>sezon</sens>
  <sens>durata</sens>
 </cuvant>
 <cuvant titlu="harnic">
  <definitie>care munceste mult, repede si cu folos</definitie>
  <sens>muncitor</sens>
  <sens>sarguincios</sens>
 </cuvant>
 <cuvant titlu="Enervat">
  <definitie>scos din fire, in stare de iritare</definitie>
  <sens>nervos</sens>
 </cuvant>
 <cuvant titlu="parfum">
  <definitie>ceva cu miros placut, frumos</definitie>
  <sens>mireasma</sens>
  <sens>esenta</sens>
  <sens>miros</sens>
  <sens>colonie</sens>
 </cuvant>
 <cuvant titlu="Eprubeta">
  <definitie>tub de sticla inchis la capat</definitie>
  <sens>tub</sens>

 </cuvant>
 <cuvant titlu="medicament">
  <definitie>substanta utilizata pentru a vindeca, ameliora sau preveni o boala</definitie>
  <sens>elixir</sens>
  <sens>leac</sens>
  <sens>remediu</sens>
 </cuvant>
</sinonime>
```

I expect the output:

Enervat

Eprubeta

because those are the elements that have only one sens (minumum count of subelements 'sens')

How to return which elements have the min subelements?

I tried:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="sinonime/cuvant">
 <xsl:sort select="count(document('sinonime.xml')//cuvat/sens)"/>
 <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
   <xsl:value-of select="@titlu"/>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `for-each` loop as in your question, you would only get 1 of the elements that have the minimum count of `sens` nodes. You can e.g. use a first `for-each` to get the minimum count and then print the `titlu` attribute valus of all `cuvant` nodes with the minimum count like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="sinonime">
  <xsl:variable name="min">
    <xsl:for-each select="cuvant">
      <xsl:sort select="count(sens)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(sens)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="cuvant[count(sens)=$min]">
   <xsl:value-of select="@titlu"/>
     <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
       <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

When applied to your input, this produces the output

```
Enervat
Eprubeta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem easily by creating first a simple document with the count and name for each "cuvant", something like:

```
<counts>
   <count name="timp" n="3"/>
   <count name="harnic" n="2"/>
   ...
</counts>
```

From there it is easy to get the minimum, select all of them where `@n` is the minimum, and display them properly (this is a complete example, the interesting part is the last 2 templates):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0">

   <xsl:variable name="doc" as="element()">
      <sinonime>
        <cuvant titlu="timp">
            <definitie>durata care corespunde desfasurarii unui evenimen</definitie>
            <sens>vreme</sens>
            <sens>sezon</sens>
            <sens>durata</sens>
        </cuvant>
        <cuvant titlu="harnic">
            <definitie>care munceste mult, repede si cu folos</definitie>
            <sens>muncitor</sens>
            <sens>sarguincios</sens>
        </cuvant>
        <cuvant titlu="Enervat">
            <definitie>scos din fire, in stare de iritare</definitie>
            <sens>nervos</sens>
        </cuvant>
        <cuvant titlu="parfum">
            <definitie>ceva cu miros placut, frumos</definitie>
            <sens>mireasma</sens>
            <sens>esenta</sens>
            <sens>miros</sens>
            <sens>colonie</sens>
        </cuvant>
        <cuvant titlu="Eprubeta">
            <definitie>tub de sticla inchis la capat</definitie>
            <sens>tub</sens>
        </cuvant>
        <cuvant titlu="medicament">
            <definitie>substanta utilizata pentru a vindeca, ameliora sau preveni o boala</definitie>
            <sens>elixir</sens>
            <sens>leac</sens>
            <sens>remediu</sens>
        </cuvant>
      </sinonime>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sinonime">
      <xsl:variable name="counts" as="element()">
         <counts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
         </counts>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="min" select="min($counts/count/xs:integer(@n))"/>
      <results>
         <xsl:for-each select="$counts/count[xs:integer(@n) eq $min]">
            <result>
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </result>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </results>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="cuvant">
      <count name="{ @titlu }" n="{ count(sens) }"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```